# Is it possible to put a long table (longtabu) into a adjust box (adjustbox)?

Tags: tables, longtable, adjustbox

I am wondering as the title says whether it is possible to put a long table, especially for me a `longtabu` into a `adjustbox`? My code throws an error but I guess this is the same issue as is with putting a `longtabu` into a `table` environment. It's not allowed as the long table cannot flow otherwise. Is that correct?

Comment: It simply doesn't make sense: In boxes like adjustbox or table there can't be a page break. So why are you trying to put a long table in such boxes?

Comment: Well, when I use the tabu environment I don't use X columns to expand the table to page width but rather manually add horizontal space between the columns. I find it much easier to organise the distance between my columns in that way than using the X column rules. You can actually pretty exactly fit the table width to page width using points as in @{\hskip 52pt}. However, to exactly fit it I wrap an adjustbox around it with \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth, totalheight=\textheight, keepaspectratio}. Probably not the best solution but it works quite fine for me :-)

Comment: I wanted to use the same trick for my longtabu but it's apparently not possible. Well, it's ok, I think it is so close to the page width that no one will spot it anyhow :)

Comment: Scaling tabulars is horrible: You will have different fontsize for each tabular.

Comment: @Josh you can put strechable glue in the `@` as in `@{\extracolsep{53pt minus 5pt plus 20pt}` so it pads the table exactly to the specified total width. Scaling tables is just wrong, the fact that it doesn't work for multi-page ones is a feature.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for you comment as well. I don't see how \extracolsep is really different to \hskip. Both add extra space to the column to stretch it? That's what I don't like about latex. There are always a 100 ways to do something, which can on the one hand be useful but on the other hand just irritating and confusing. And also the change of combining things which you shouldn't combine as they actually come from different well let's say sources/packages often happens when you are not an expert in latex...

Comment: @Josh you can not add stretchable space directly in `@` which is why you are manually having to guess the widths. If you use `\extracolsep` it can stretch so can automatically expand the table to textwidth

Answer (score 2):

To automatically adjust the intercolumn space specify the total table width using tabu or longtable syntax and then add stretchable glue between the columns via

```
@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
```